# How can I progmatically generate bitcoin address with in WASABI Deskstop wallet?

Tags: address-generation, wasabi-wallet

I would like to generate 10000 btc address and save it as csv file on my computer to be uploaded it on my server. I hope anyone can help me find the solution. 
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a hacky way, but you can export the xpub/zpub to electrum and do it there with a bit of Python.

Another option would be to use the same public key with this website that seems to be able to generates a CSV of addresses: https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

Comment: My Wasabi xpub was not accepted on https://iancoleman.io/bip39/  and it only accepts root keys or mnemonic word conversion.

Comment: bummer. well, for sure electrum would let you do it (I've done it myself). worth a try. and the console is basically a python REPL so you can get it to spit out a CSV probably

Answer (score 1):

I think this doc will be helpful. https://docs.wasabiwallet.io/FAQ/FAQ-UseWasabi.html#what-derivation-paths-does-wasabi-use

> Wasabi follows BIP 84: Derivation scheme for P2WPKH Based Accounts, so
>   the main path is m/84'/0'/0'. On TestNet and RegTest Wasabi uses
>   m/84'/0'/0', and not the standard m/84'/1'/0'. Due to the CoinJoin
>   implementation, the key depth can be rather large, thus when
>   recovering the gap limit should be elevated to at least 100.

And here are all the BIPs Wasabi supports: https://docs.wasabiwallet.io/using-wasabi/BIPs.html